# Como guardo una imagen elegida desde la galeria y que al cambiar de activity no se me borre

Tags: android, kotlin

estoy usando kotlin en Android Studio y no consigo que la imagen que escojo de la galería cuando cambio de activity o cierro la app se me quede fija. Si alguien puede ayudar gracias.

Esto es lo que tengo hasta el momento para abrir la galeria y seleccionar una foto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muestra un [repro] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento: lee [ask].

Comment: Ya esta, soy nuevo y simplemente quería saber como se hace

Comment: Bienvenido, recuerda que es importante revisar [ask] para evitar la pregunta sea cerrada, saludos.